# Paypal ipn sent successfully but not insert into database

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

The previous day I tested paypal subscription with ipn. My button code is like this :

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">                                            
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="yann@gmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Small Plan">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://192.168.0.144:90/Ecatalogue/plan/payment-successful.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://192.168.0.144:90/Ecatalogue/plan/payment-cancelled.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="22.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-SubscriptionsBF:btn_subscribe_LG.gif:NonHosted">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://192.168.0.144:90/Ecatalogue/ipn.php">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribe_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

My ipn code is :

```
<?php
include("config.php");

global $DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD, $DB_NAME,$SERVER_PATH;

$con = mysql_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD);
mysql_select_db($DB_NAME, $con);

// STEP 1: Read POST data

// reading posted data from directly from $_POST causes serialization 
// issues with array data in POST
// reading raw POST data from input stream instead. 
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
  $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
  if (count($keyval) == 2)
     $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
   $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
} 
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {        
   if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) { 
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
   } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
   }
   $req .= "&$key=$value";
}


// STEP 2: Post IPN data back to paypal to validate

$ch = curl_init('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

// In wamp like environments that do not come bundled with root authority certificates,
// please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path 
// of the certificate as shown below.
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
    // error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);


// STEP 3: Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly

if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process payment

    // assign posted variables to local variables
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];


    mysql_query("INSERT INTO transactions (tran_plan) VALUES ('$item_name')");

} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation
}
?>
```

When I test on ipn simulator on paypal developer site, I got "IPN Sent Successfully ". But this not insert in database. In IPN history , the ipn status is "sent". If you have any solutions, please answer me as soon as possible.

Comment: I don't see any actual db insert commands in your code..??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use **mysqli_query()**  ??

At least you can try ;)

Doc: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php